# Is an element of a set that is contained within a larger set also an element of the larger set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have A = {1, 2, 3} and B = {4, 5, 6}.

Now suppose you have set C = {{A, B}}.

Of course, 3 ∈ A.

My question is: is it also the case that 3 ∈ C? C seems to contain 3 in some sense, but is it correct to say that 3 is element of C?

Edit: abiessu points out that I have written that A is an element of a set which is an element in C. This is not what I intedned to write, it was an error on my part. Let me now correct that. I meant to say that C = {A,B}.

Comment: No.  $3$ is an element of (an element of) one of the elements of $C$.  If $A$ is a *subset* of $C$, then $3\in A\to 3\in C$.

Comment: Do note that the word "contain" is used for both $\in$ and $\subseteq$ on many occasions, so it is up to you to make the context and understand which one is meant (sometimes both will work), and it is up to the author to make sure that you are able to do that properly.

Comment: @abiessu Thanks. I'm still a bit confused though. You say "If  is a subset of , then 3∈→3∈."  is a subset of  in the example I provided, so we have the antecedent for this conditional. It follows that 3∈→3∈. We also have the antecedent for this conditional, since 3∈. Does it not follow that 3 is an element of C?

Comment: The way you wrote the set definition of $C$, $A$ is an element of a set which is an element in $C$ (literal translation of the set notation used).  To write a set $C$ for which $A,B$ are subsets, one notation is $C=\{a,b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Comment: @abiessu Ah! I am so sorry. That's an error on my part. I will edit the question. It should read C = {A, B}.

Comment: Notation is still an issue, since $C=\{A,B\}$ says that $C$ is a set having elements $A,B$.

Comment: Ah jeez. Ok. Well, I am struggling to find the right notation to ask this question then. So I'll just take a stab at this without notation. It seems intuitive that some set C could contain as an element a set A that itself contains as elements 1, 2, and 3. I just want to know if, in this case, it is reasonable to say "3 is an element of C", or if I would need to say "3 is an element of an element of C", which is more cumbersome and irritating to read.

Comment: Skipping the notation entirely, you might write "let $A,B$ be such and such sets and $C$ be a set with $A,B$ as subsets".

Comment: As in the answer below, set membership is not generally transitive, so the answer is no, you would need to say the extra "an element of" for clarity.

Comment: @abiessu All right! Thanks for the help. I will make sure to write the extra 'is an element of' for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set membership relation $\in$ is not transitive. $x\in{y}$ and $y\in{z}$ does not, in general, imply $x\in{z}.$ Consider the set $S=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}.$ The sets $A=\{0\},$ $B=\{1\},$ $C=\{2\}$ are the three elements of $S.$ Also, $0\in{A},$ $1\in{B},$ $2\in{C}.$ Yet it is not the case that $0\in{S},$ or $1\in{S},$ or $2\in{S}.$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. This is puzzling to me (a complete novice), because it seems so intuitive to think that in your example S still contains 0 in some sense, even if 0 is not an element of S for some formal reasons I'm not comprehending.

Comment: @dfi6ju: we could confuse the issue further by writing the set $T=\{0,\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$, for example.  Then $0\in T$ is a valid statement.

Comment: @dfi6ju: I understand what you are getting at, but I think the problem is that the set membership relation $\in$ does not work in the way your intuition is telling you it works. I would recommend that you try learning further about set theory to get a comprehensive definition and understanding for what exactly it means for a set to be an element of another set.

Comment: @dfi6ju Let me try to see if this helps you. Do you think the sets $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$ are the same set, or different sets?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve one of the goals stated in the comments, it is possible to adjust the language slightly so that the repetition in "$3$ is an element of an element of $C$" is not necessary.  For example, the word "contains" is ambiguous enough within set theory that we could provide our own meaning, perhaps as follows:

Let "$U$ is a descendant of $V$" mean that there is a finite sequence $E_0,E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{n-1},E_n$ such that $U\in E_n\in E_{n-1}\in \dots\in E_2\in E_1\in E_0\in V$.  Further, when either $K\in V$ or $K$ is a descendant of $V$ we say that $V$ contains $K$.

In the context of the sets in the question, we could then say that $C$ contains $3$.  Note that this definition of "contains" is different from "has subset".  It should be straightforward to prove that this definition is transitive.